# Get inserted document's ObjectID after insert in MongoDB PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, insert

I have inserted a row to mongodb with php and I need to get the row's is.

```
<?php
$mongoconnect=new MongoClient();
$mongo=$mongoconnect->smartpass;
$user=$mongo->test->insert(array("test"=>"test"));
foreach($user as $doc){
    $user_a[]=$doc;
}
var_dump($user_a);
?>
```

The result doesn't contains the `"_id"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `insert` method doesn't return the (modified) document, but only a status object.

Instead, you'll have to pass a named variable so you can access the modified variable for reading. As explained in the docs][1](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.insert.php):

```
// If an array literal is used, there is no way to access the generated _id
$collection->insert(array('x' => 1));

// The _id is available on an array passed by value
$a = array('x' => 2);
$collection->insert($a);
var_dump($a);
```